# What CSS selector is this? [ui-view].ng-enter-active

Tags: css, css-selectors

What CSS selector is the first part in square brackets?

```
[ui-view].ng-enter-active {}
```

It is not an attribute selector that would be this right?

```
ui-view[content] {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed an attribute selector. An attribute selector and a class selector are both [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn), and simple selectors in a sequence may be arranged in any order, with the exception that a type or universal selector, if present, must come first.

This means `[ui-view].ng-enter-active` and `.ng-enter-active[ui-view]` are both valid and equivalent, matching an element that has a class "ng-enter-active" as well as an attribute named "ui-view". The former seems strange at first only because you rarely see attribute selectors appearing first in a simple selector sequence.

Your second example, `ui-view[content]`, contains a type selector, `ui-view`. Because of this, unlike your first example, it *cannot* be rewritten as `[content]ui-view`, since, as mentioned, type selectors must come first.

Comment: ".ng-enter-active[ui-view]" This seems strange to me true. If you meant the same with former...

Comment: @msfanboy: No, by former I mean `[ui-view].ng-enter-active` - that other one would be the *latter*. But why would that seem strange to you, considering you listed the second example yourself (with the attribute selector appearing last) and asserted that that was indeed an attribute selector?

Comment: When I do: ui-view[content].ng-enter then my animations do not run anymore although I have defined ui-view="content" on the div. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is an attribute selector. It would select an element that has both a `ui-view` attribute as well as the class `ng-enter-active`. That attribute selector doesn't care about the actual value of the attribute. So for example, it would correctly select the following:

```
<div ui-view class="ng-enter-active"></div>
```

as well as:

```
<div ui-view="valueDoesntMatter" class="ng-enter-active"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's attribute selector, so:

The first one

```
[ui-view].ng-enter-active
```

means element with class `ng-enter-active` and attribute `ui-view`, eg.

```
<div class="ng-enter-active" ui-view="abc">
<div class="ng-enter-active" ui-view> <!-- or with attribute without value -->
```

The second one,

```
ui-view[content]
```

means element `ui-view` (you probably forgot dot, `class="ui-view"`) with attribute `content`

```
<ui-view content="abc">
```

OR probably, if you forgot `.` in selector

```
<div class="ui-view" content="whatever">
```

See more about attribute selector: http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_attribute.html